# Is there a more concise way to combine many comparisons in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, comparison, if-statement

I currently have this if statement:

```
if Time.now.day == 1 and Time.now.hour == 0 and Time.now.minute == 0 and Time.now.second == 0
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: btw, wouldn't doing Time.now give you a new current time each time you call it? Wouldn't it be better to set Time.now to a local variable first, then use it in if statement? I suppose it depends on what you really want...

Comment: It will return different values, only they'll be different by a tiny slice of a second. Theoretically it's possible that the time could transition from 00:00:00 to 00:00:01. Try this in IRB: `5.times { puts Time.now.to_f }` to get an idea how fast the conditions would be tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Ruby Time library is pretty spare, so I would simply add my own method to make this easier:

```
class Time
  def beginning_of_month
    Time.local(self.year, self.month, 1)
  end

  def beginning_of_month?
    self == beginning_of_month
  end
end
```

so you could then write:

```
if Time.now.beginning_of_month?
```

Comment: I don't see the change method on the standard doc either
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous comment accidentally. Original comment was (somewhat similar to): I don't see it working when I run it. What version of ruby are you using? Mine's 1.8.7. When run, it spits out this error: undefined method `change' for Tue Nov 30 16:07:18 +1100 2010:Time (NoMethodError)

Comment: @tim_wonil you're right, I think my irb was pulling in activesupport without my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Time#to_a](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000273) to convert your time to an array (sec, min, hour, day, month, year, wday, yday, isdst, zone):

```
Time.now.to_a  # => [20, 57, 16, 30, 11, 2010, 2, 334, false, "CET"]
```

then slice off just the part you want to match against:

```
Time.now.to_a[0,4]  # => [20, 57, 16, 30]
```

Your particular check can then be made as concise as this:

```
if Time.now.to_a[0,4] == [0,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[:day,:hour,:minute,:second].map{|s|Time.now.send s}==[1,0,0,0]
```

Comment: @Jergason: What do you mean? This is idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: The bit that's bugging me is the `{|s|Time.now.send s}`. It seems like you should be able to eliminate the `s` points.

Comment: you can do [...].map(&Time.now.method(:send))==[...]. It has hidden benifit to compute time once.

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
Time.now.strftime('%d %H:%M:%S') == '01 00:00:00'
```

I like this because it's very self-documenting; It's obvious you're comparing to a certain day at midnight.

Explanation: The `strftime()` method makes it easy to output a custom date and/or time string. This format is outputting the day of the month, hour, minute and second.

```
Time.now.strftime('%d %H:%M:%S') #=> "01 16:54:24"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it to a time you created:

```
if Time.now == Time.at(0)
```

or

```
if Time.now == Time.utc(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are trying to make something similar to `cron`, i.e. you are in an endless loop and checking whether time has come to perform certain action.

If that is the case, I don't think you should rely that your timestamp check will fall exactly on the first second of the day. What would happen if is delayed (for any reason), and first it fires on `23:59:59`, and the next cycle happens on `00:00:01` instead of `:00`? You will fail to perform desired action whatsoever.

Also, you would want to include some `sleep`, so that your empty loop wouldn't consume all you resources while waiting.

What you could do instead, is keep the last action timestamp, and compare `now` with the next action timestamp, performing the action if `now >= next_timestamp`. Something like:

```
last_action_on = Time.at(0)
loop do
  now = Time.now
  next_action_on = Time.local(now.year, now.month, 1) # beginning of the current day
  if last_action_on < next_action_on && now >= next_action_on
    last_action_on = now
    do_action
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 %w(day==1 hour==0 minute==0 second==0).all? { |e| eval "Time.now.#{e}" }
```